# No Referer header in CORS request from IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cors, preflight

I'm trying to send a CORS POST request to an server.

In Chrome, this works as expected - OPTIONS preflight request is sent to server, server responds with access control headers, POST request is sent. When I try to do this in IE or Firefox, no referer is sent with the OPTIONS request, so I cannot add the access-control-allow-origin header (as this is done programatically).

Javascript is:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'POST',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true,
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
    });
    return false;
});
```

The headers in Chrome are as follows: 
[image: Chrome headers]

The headers in Firefox are as follows:
[image: Firefox headers]

Is there a way to guarantee that the referrer will be sent with the OPTIONS preflight request? And if not - is there another way to get the referring URL so I can add the allow origin header?

Comment: Why do you need to know the referring URL? Usually `Allow-Origin` is set based on the actual security policies; in other words, the site is configured to allow some particular origins, or all origins.

Comment: There are a few different URLs that need to have access, and the urls change depending on the environment (live, staging etc). So I check the incoming url against a list of acceptable ones. If it's in there, I add the allow origin header to be the incoming url.

Comment: Ah OK - learn something every day; I had assumed that the CORS header could include a list of URLs, but apparently it's either one origin or `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by using the Origin header that is sent along with the preflight request. So if the Origin URL is one of the acceptable hosts, add the access-control-allow-origin header with the originating url.